# Alfresco REST API:Data Size Limit?

Tags: rest, alfresco

I am developing REST based webservices in alfresco for data transfer & want to know what is the maximum amount of data i can send/get thru REST protocol?

Any reference would be very helpful.

Regards.

Comment: what's your return type? XML or JSON?

Comment: I want send binary content such as a pdf file from alfresco to third party system as well as json content.

Comment: What makes you think there's a fixed limit?

Comment: Alfresco has other useful protocols for uploading binary data, stuff like CMIS or FTP (within corporate firewalls of course). Maybe you can also use other stuff?
Nevertheless, very interesting question.

Comment: I am trying to make an assumption before implementing REST based content transfer engine & just want to get an official version for same.

Comment: Does REST depends upon HTTP protocol for data transfer & its limits?

Answer (score 2):

The max amount of data is as large as 2147000000. That's why if your data is large enough it is advisable to stream it to post to your REST service. Here's an example.

**Sender/ Uploader Application or Client**

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Just test data. You can send large one also");
        var postData = sb.ToString();
        var url = "REST Post method example http://localhost:2520/DataServices/TestPost";
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
        dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, postData);
        var xmlData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", "");
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml";
        client.UploadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        {
            if (ea.Error != null) Console.WriteLine("An error has occured while processing your request");
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(ea.Result);
            if (doc.Root != null) Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Value);
            if (doc.Root != null && doc.Root.Value.Contains("1"))
            {
                string test = "test";
            }
        };
```

**REST Service method**

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "TestPost", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string Publish(string market,string sportId, Stream streamdata)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);
        var res = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

    }
```

**Don't forget to put the following configuration settings on your REST Service config file if you don't have this it will throw you an error**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147000000" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    ........
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147000000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147000000" maxBufferSize="2147000000"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is there any official reference to limit of 2147000000. If yes, can you please share it?